# Why is CSS not taking effect?

Tags: html, css

On the following page is body text, including some bullet text. I need the bullet text to be the same (larger) size as the body text.

http://www.a-quick-sale.co.uk/howitworks/

There is a global stylesheet in the site (/global.css) and I added an entry to it:

```
li { font-size: 14px;}
```

But that font-size style is not being applied. I don't want to start being lazy and applying styles directly to page context, but why is the global style I created not being applied?

I've not done any work with CSS or HTML for over a decade, so please be gentle - the answer is likely obvious to anyone with current skills.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I reckon you got your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `div#content li` is more specific than just a single type selector, you need to include elements that are higher up in the cascade to override the specifcity

Specificity can be thought of as four numbers (0,0,0,0)

- Inline styles are the first - highest precedence
- ID selectors are the second number
- Pseudo-classes and attribute selectors are the third
- Type selectors are the fourth
- The universal selector `*` has a specificity of 0, anything will override it.

So just specifying `li` has a value of (0,0,0,1) vs `div#content li` which has a specificity of (0,1,0,1) the latter wins. Just use this concept to come up with a higher selector.

Answer (score 2):

In the global.css file there is a more specific selector `div#content li` that has `font-size` selected inside of it. Be as specific with your selector, or more specific for it to apply throughout the content area.

Answer (score 2):

In the same global.css, there is a `div#content li { font-size: 12px;}` which is applied, because it is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the style, like this:

```
li { font-size: 14px !important ;}
```

So it gets priority over existent styles for that element.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome Developer Tools (F12) you can see which styles are being applied to each element, and even see styles being overridden as they are crossed out, very helpful for debugging CSS issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the same file, at line 208 you define `div#content li {font-size: 12px;}` which is more accurate than just `li`.

Answer (score 0):

I should say you need to apply styling to links itself, while it's not just a plain text inside `li`.

```
li a { font-size: 14px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

On 108 line of your global.css you have a CSS rule `div#content li { font-size: 12px;}`  that overrides your: `li { font-size: 14px;}` rule.